# Removing header/footer/other elements from an HTML Object page?

Tags: html, jquery, html-object

I am currently using the HTML Object element to embed a page within another page on my application by passing the link of the page I wish to embed to the object element's data property like so:

```
<object data="www.someurl.com"></object>
```

To make things clear, let's say I am passing the link of page A to an object element to embed page A within page B. What I am wondering is if there is any way to remove the header and footer of page A within the object element? It sort of looks repetitive because page B also holds the same header and footer, so I am wondering if it is possible to remove the header and footer from the object element.

If it helps, the application is using jQuery in case there is some solution there.

Comment: If on the same server you can do use jQuery, and do `$("#someContentDiv").load("page.html #containerDiv")` If not on the same server, then you cannot modify the page at all

Comment: _Element_, not tag. Tags are just text in a file.